# Shodan scan results via API

Tags: python, shodan

I'm trying to download Shodan scan results via Python api but I'm not able to retrieve any values.

I have following code:

```
api=Shodan('API_KEY')
api.scan(XXXX/24)
api.scan_status('SCAN_ID')
api.search('scan:SCAN_ID')
```

despite scan status showing as DONE, I'm not able to retrieve any results:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MrDY.png)

```
{'count': 512, 'status': 'DONE', 'id': 'SCAN_ID', 'created': '2023-04-11T08:51:08.448000'}
{'matches': [], 'total': 0}
```

Probably I'm doing something terribly wrong here but I'm not able to find a solution.